# Why is this function first in this Jquery code?

Tags: jquery, callback

I have a code that goes something like this

```
verify_loaded_css.check (function (){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(300, function (){
        $(this).remove(); 
    }); 
}); 

verify_loaded_css = {
    check: function (runCallback){
        if (..) {
            ..
            runCallback(); 
        } else {
            ..
        }
    }
}
```

I placed console.log with random numbers to see which functions run first (Any better way to do this?). I see that the check function (runCallback) runs first, which I'm trying to understand the logic. When you have an anonymous function, I assume it auto-executes whatever is after/in it which is the #overlay fading out. Instead somehow it's runCallback function first which runs the if statement, and calls runCallback() again if true. Then at the very end, it fades the overlay out.

Does this mean that any anonymous function isn't self-executing and it'll run whatever code elsewhere first if you declared it something else?

Thank you

Comment: Are they in that order in the code? Because if so, it should be throwing an error for verify_loaded_css not being declared..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that any anonymous function isn't self-executing and it'll run whatever code elsewhere first if you declared it something else?

Correct, anonymous functions are *not* self-executing.

Functions are run in the order that they are called, just like in other languates, but as ai.farfa mentions functions are objects and can be passed around, hence the notion of callbacks.

You say:

> I see that the check function (runCallback) runs first

But a better way to write it is as:

```
check(function(){/* code in here */})
```

So what happens is that you enter into `check`, and `runCallback` is bound to the [function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) that is defined as its argument.

So this is semantically similar (it would be semantically identical if js wasn't such a [weird language](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)) to:

```
function myFadout() {/* code in here */};

check(myFadout);
```

In both cases the argument to `check` represents the same *sequence of operations*, and function objects are just a convenient abstraction—whether named or nameless.
And thus once you get to the line `runCallback()`, since `runCallback` is bound to `myFadout`, what happens *is* semantically equivalent to `myFadout()`.

Answer (score 1):

in javascript every thing is object. even a "function"

You may declare instant of function

**Hint*** read from the bottom-up.

```
var fadeoutCallback = function (element){
    $(element).remove(); 
}

var checkCallback = function(){
    //alert("fadeout the overlay");
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(300, fadeoutCallback); 
}

//a function that accept another instant of function
var check = function(callback){
    if(confirm("checking some condition?") == true){
        callback();
    }
}

//finally an object act as "class"
myClass = {
    myMethod: check
}

//then calling class.method
myClass.myMethod(checkCallback);
```

Comment: It's not quite that simple. `typeof 1 === 'number'`, but `typeof new Number(1) === 'object'`. (Similarly for other primitives.) That's not all, though; it's even more complex because of boxing and unboxing. I think your answer would be more clear and correct if you called them *values* rather than *objects*.

Comment: thanks, also `typeof function () {} === "function"` but you can treat it like a value.